# Angular.js and socket.io not working properly - nothing is showing up on the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets

First of all, my socket connection works fine and I tested it. But when I emit a socket to the client and try to update page nothing happens. Any idea how to do this?

Receiveing socket : Angular controller

```
.controller("DepositsCtrl", function (mySocket, $scope) {
        $scope.deposits = [];
        mySocket.on('sendRound', function(data) {
            $scope.deposits.push =
                {
                    steamId: data.steamId,
                    itemCount: data.itemCount,
                    depositValue: data.depositValue
                }
        });
```

And my html file :

```
<div class="section" ng-controller="DepositsCtrl">
            <h2>Deposits</h2>
            <hr class="line-under">
            <section class="round">
                <ul ng-repeat="deposit in deposits">
                    <li><div class="deposit-person">{{deposit.steamId}}</div></li>
                    <li><div class="deposit-items">{{deposit.itemCount}}</div></li>
                    <li><div class="deposit-value">{{deposit.depositValue}}</div></li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </div>
```

I want this to add new record on the page real time when socket  is being emitted with data.

Comment: It looks like with `$scope.deposits.push =`, you're setting `deposits.push` to be the object. I think you meant `$scope.deposits.push({ ... })`..

Comment: @AndrewKoroluk you're probably right, I'm going to check this.

Comment: @AndrewKoroluk unfortunately nothing changed, still not working.

Comment: I have no idea what `mySocket` is. Have you confirmed that your `mySocket.on` callback is actually getting called?

Comment: Yes it is working properly, I've checked.

Comment: First you need to change your push function like this `$scope.deposits.push({ ... })` and then make sure that your `mySocket` service is getting injected properly (Check in console for errors). And then try putting some console statements in your mySocket.on function to check whether it is getting called or not ?. If nothing happens then please post your back-end code where you are emitting the data.

Comment: @Achu Thanks I got it almost working. If someone is on the page and new record is being pushed it displays on page, but when I refresh it or try to push another one nothing happens. Any idea how to change this?